# Can we check whether a table exists in the time of joining in MySql query

Tags: mysql

I like to join two tables T1 and T2.

T1 is my left table and T2 is my right.

```
`SELECT
    DISTINCT T1.name AS 'name',
    T1.volume AS 'volume',
    T1.vserver AS 'vserver',
    T1.cluster AS 'cluster',
    T1.snapmirror_label AS 'snapmirror_label',
    T1.timestamp AS 'timestamp'
FROM
    schema3.snapmirror_policy_rule snapmirror_policy_rule,
    schema3.vserver vserver,
    schema3.cluster cluster,
    schema1.T1 T1
LEFT JOIN
    schema2.T2
        ON schema1.T1.name = schema2.T2.name
....
`
```

My question is, if the table T2 doesn't exist, how will I perform?

My idea is to join two tables if both the tables (T1 as well as T2) exist, else based on few conditions, I will select rows from my T1 table (which exists always) only. I'm looking for the query in these contexts.

PS:- In my working env, procedure like complex thing will not work. Looking for simple straight forward MySql query.

Comment: How is it possible that you don't know if table exists?

Comment: So my intention is, if T2 exists, do something, else do another thing. I need to check whether T2 exists or not. `SELECT count(table_name) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 WHERE table_schema = 'schema2'
 AND table_name LIKE 'T2'`  But don't know how to put it into some CASE/IF THEN ELSE type of statement so that joining can be performed